# Integration Question with Root of Trigonometric functions at the Bottom

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$$\int ^{\frac{\pi}{2}} _{0} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1+\mathrm{cos}\ x)(\mathrm{sin}\ x + \mathrm{cos}\ x)}}$$
I tried using double angle formula to convert $\sqrt{(1+\mathrm{cos}\ x}$ to $\sqrt{2}\ \mathrm{cos}\ \frac{x}{2}$ and then $\sqrt{\mathrm{sin}\ x + \mathrm{cos}\ x} = \sqrt{2\ \mathrm{sin}\ \frac{x}{2}\ \mathrm{cos}\ \frac{x}{2} + 1 - 2\ \mathrm{sin}^2 \frac{x}{2}}$ =  $\sqrt{(\mathrm{sin}\ \frac{x}{2} + \mathrm{cos}\ \frac{x}{2})^2 - \ 2\ \mathrm{sin}^2 \frac{x}{2}}$. But I am not sure what to do after that. Also I tried $f(x) = f(\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$ and then adding them together and then using double angle formulas like above, but I still couldn't solve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: weierstrass works----

Comment: I agree :) $\phantom{}$

Comment: @tired What is weierstrass?

Comment: thae weierstrass substitution. it is nicely exposed in Jack's answer

Comment: @tired oh, so it is when you do the substitution: z = arctan t. Is there specific cases when you use this. Like how would you know when to use it?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstra%C3%9F-Substitution
your questition is an example where it works outside of its ''usual range''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\cos\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}}=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{dz}{\cos(z)\sqrt{\sin(2z)+\cos(2z)}}$$
becomes, by setting  $z=\arctan t$,
$$ I = \sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}\sqrt{-1+2\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}}}=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+2t-t^2}}$$
or:
$$ I = \sqrt{2}\,\left.\arcsin\left(\frac{t-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|_{0}^{1} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}}.$$

Comment: ah...nice (+1)!